# Selecting a default picture with radio button in a new nested attributes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a Rails project which has a car model and it has multiple pictures. I've created a nested form so I can input the cars details and pictures all at the same time. I would like a radio button to select the picture to display in the gallery.

```
 %table
    = simple_form_for [@car] :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
        = f.error_messages 
        = f.input :make
        = f.input :model
        = f.input :engine
        = f.input :price

        = f.simple_fields_for :car_pictures do |builder|
            .picture
                = builder.input :caption
                = builder.input :picture
                .thumb= image_tag builder.object.picture(:thumb)

        = f.button :submit
```

Is it possible to use a radio button in the 'fields_for' section to select the default/main picture? Or is there a better way?

**Update**

By putting the following under the fields_for all the radio buttons work independently, which is not what I want.

```
= builder.radio_button(:favourite, "test")
```

Each radio button is getting a unique name.

**Update**

What if I used the object_id as the value, how would I go about linking this in the create method?

```
= f.radio_button(:favourite_pic, builder.object_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your last guess was correct. I made a test application in which the customer can select a favorite photo: https://github.com/eicca/attrs_test (see commit changes marked by "added favorite example").

There are two main points (according to your situation):

```
= f.radio_button(:favorite_pic_id, builder.object.id)
```

and

```
#models/car
has_one :favorite_pic, :class_name => "CarPicture"
```

And you need to add `favorite_pic_id` field to your `cars` table.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use 'belongs_to' on the car model? eg: belongs_to :car_picture, :foreign_key => :favorite_pic_id

Comment: You do not necessarily to do it, if you do not want to do this: `car_picture -> car` to obtain the car, where this picture is favorite. In this case you must to add `has_one` to `CarPicture` and some other declaration.
My example is only for association: `car.favorite_pic`. I am using `has_one` instead of `belongs_to` because I think it helps more clearly to understand, that it one-to-one association in this case. But it is a matter of taste, I guess. Sorry for spelling )

Answer (score 0):

Why not? :) Only selected radio button will be sent to the server. So, only thing you've got to do - is to give it proper name/value and make sure that you have an accessor for it to support mass-assignment.

Comment: If I put a radio_button in the fields_for section they are not part of the same group.